# image not displaying correctly, should be vertical

Tags: html, css

The following html is not displaying the image correctly. The image is 233 by 144 and is a vertical image, but it is displaying in the page horizontally.

```html
<p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://machineryrestorations.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles/blogs/dewalt_RAS_GE/images/GE_LongArm_PreDelivery_Kraked_W377xH233.jpg" alt="Long Arm pre-delivery" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci orci, efficitur nec pretium at, iaculis elementum sapien. Etiam id metus quis metus semper ullamcorper nec non dui. Aliquam aliquam tempus orci, eget laoreet erat dignissim non. Maecenas sed leo blandit, condimentum ipsum et, aliquam libero. Ut neque lacus, viverra quis ipsum vitae, lobortis rhoncus neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vehicula consectetur augue, quis iaculis turpis gravida in.
        <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci orci, efficitur nec pretium at, iaculis elementum sapien. Etiam id metus quis metus semper ullamcorper nec non dui. Aliquam aliquam tempus orci, eget laoreet erat dignissim non. Maecenas sed leo blandit, condimentum ipsum et, aliquam libero. Ut neque lacus, viverra quis ipsum vitae, lobortis rhoncus neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vehicula consectetur augue, quis iaculis turpis gravida in.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</p>
```

[image: picture displaying horizontally]

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Clearly this has transitional CSS applied to it

Comment: If the image is local then open the image in image viewer rotate it and save it.No need of HTML or CSS.

Comment: There is no specific css applied to this html other than the bootstrap css. Do images display horizontally by default? Because this image is normally vertical.

Comment: It is requested to be wider than high so it is rotated by the server which seems to read the parameters in the file name.

`W377xH233`

Comment: @mplungjan...any way to resolve this? Remove the parameters from the filename?

Comment: How should I know? I do not run the service you got the image from. Interestingly google will rotate it if I paste the URL into the location

Comment: @mplungjan...Google isn't rotating it, that's how the image is, vertical.

Comment: Server issue...just do rotate it - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/269/

Comment: How can it be vertical when it is specified to be wider than tall?

Comment: It would be smarter to upload it after rotating it on the device

Comment: Nice downvotes by the uninformed, The image IS vertical, and if you saw it in my file explorer you would see that, thus the question. Hardly a stupid one when every other image on that page from the same image folder displays correctly.

Comment: @mplungjan...how does one accomplish uploading it after rotating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rotate it

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/269/)**

**DEMO HERE TOO**

```css
img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://machineryrestorations.blob.core.windows.net/publicfiles/blogs/dewalt_RAS_GE/images/GE_LongArm_PreDelivery_Kraked_W377xH233.jpg" alt="Long Arm pre-delivery" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci orci, efficitur nec pretium at, iaculis elementum sapien. Etiam id metus quis metus semper ullamcorper nec non dui. Aliquam aliquam tempus orci, eget laoreet erat dignissim
      non. Maecenas sed leo blandit, condimentum ipsum et, aliquam libero. Ut neque lacus, viverra quis ipsum vitae, lobortis rhoncus neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vehicula consectetur
      augue, quis iaculis turpis gravida in.
      <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci orci, efficitur nec pretium at, iaculis elementum sapien. Etiam id metus quis metus semper ullamcorper nec non dui. Aliquam aliquam tempus orci, eget laoreet erat dignissim
      non. Maecenas sed leo blandit, condimentum ipsum et, aliquam libero. Ut neque lacus, viverra quis ipsum vitae, lobortis rhoncus neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vehicula consectetur
      augue, quis iaculis turpis gravida in.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with the code. it's the image. use the image from local, it works. i have changed the image and it looks all fine

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3247/nature-forest-industry-rails.jpg" alt="Long Arm pre-delivery" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci orci, efficitur nec pretium at, iaculis elementum sapien. Etiam id metus quis metus semper ullamcorper nec non dui. Aliquam aliquam tempus orci, eget laoreet erat dignissim non. Maecenas sed leo blandit, condimentum ipsum et, aliquam libero. Ut neque lacus, viverra quis ipsum vitae, lobortis rhoncus neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vehicula consectetur augue, quis iaculis turpis gravida in.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed orci orci, efficitur nec pretium at, iaculis elementum sapien. Etiam id metus quis metus semper ullamcorper nec non dui. Aliquam aliquam tempus orci, eget laoreet erat dignissim non. Maecenas sed leo blandit, condimentum ipsum et, aliquam libero. Ut neque lacus, viverra quis ipsum vitae, lobortis rhoncus neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam vehicula consectetur augue, quis iaculis turpis gravida in.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```